# Tomcat plugins for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I am very new to android , I have created a chat application in android but it is not complete I want to use a server , I think for now I may use tomcat , and  is there any addition of plugins for the use of tomcat with eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not host a database on tomcat, you can just host web based applications on it which intern need to use some kind of database like MySQL etc., 
Anyway, i think i understood what you are trying to do,follow these steps:

1.Install some kind of database (MySQL) on your PC

2.Create a web application which can edit/read the database

3.expose services for those operation so that any client do CRUD operations on DB

4.Deploy it on tomcat

5.Create an app for android which can use the services which you exposed in point 3.

For the question you asked wether you will need more plugins,1 option is you can download J2EE based plugins to easily create a quick web app, or may be hibernate plugins for ORM support etc.,

Using localhost: it will refer back to emulator, to access your development machine use 10.0.2.2

Im sure this link will be useful - [click here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: Well Thanks a lot Tekkavi, can you suggest the plugins for dynamic web apps and  servlet for Eclipse?

Comment: This is eclipse for J2EE, you can install ADT on it
http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1